# executing a few command lines from java

Tags: java, command-line

I want to execute those few lines from java code but I didn't know how.

```
cd C:\\apps\\dcm4che-2.0.28\\dcm4che-tool\\dcm4che-tool-txt2dcmsr\\src\\bin 

txt2dcmsr.bat -c C:\\apps\\dcm4che-2.0.28\\dcm4che-tool\\dcm4che-tool-txt2dcmsr\\src\\etc\\txt2dcmsr.cfg C:\\Users\\intidhar\\Desktop\\input\\tst.txt \"C:\\Users\\intidhar\\Desktop\\output\\tst.dcm
```

I wrote those lines of java code but it didn't work:

```
try { 
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    runtime.exec("C:\\apps\\dcm4che-2.0.28\\dcm4che-tool\\dcm4che-tool-txt2dcmsr\\src\\bin\\txt2dcmsr.bat -c \"C:\\apps\\dcm4che-2.0.28\\dcm4che-tool\\dcm4che-tool-txt2dcmsr\\src\\etc\\txt2dcmsr.cfg\" \"C:\\Users\\intidhar\\Desktop\\input\\tst.txt\" \"C:\\Users\\intidhar\\Desktop\\output\\tst.dcm\"");
    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Is this command works in command prompt? if yes it should here as well. I see you only the last arugument is in double quotes but in the program all of them are enclosed in double queotes, not sure if that's the issue. runtime.exec(...) will return a Process object, from that read the error/output and see what its throwing.

Comment: yes, it works in command prompt. but in java, it didn't work

Comment: did you check what errors the Process object is returning?

Comment: it is returning no error

Comment: but I don't get the tst.dcm file